# Will Anaconda Python config scripts clash with Homebrew's?

Tags: python, homebrew

Will Anaconda Python config scripts clash with Homebrew's?  Note that I do not use these config scripts in any of my workflows, I'm just wondering if any of these config scripts may get called "behind the scenes".  Sample output below (with username replaced by '..'):

```
$ brew doctor
...
Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
```

Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

```
  /Users/../anaconda/bin/curl-config
  /Users/../anaconda/bin/freetype-config
  /Users/../anaconda/bin/libdynd-config
  /Users/../anaconda/bin/libpng-config
  /Users/../anaconda/bin/libpng15-config
  /Users/../anaconda/bin/llvm-config
  /Users/../anaconda/bin/python-config
  /Users/../anaconda/bin/python2-config
  /Users/../anaconda/bin/python2.7-config
  /Users/../anaconda/bin/xml2-config
  /Users/../anaconda/bin/xslt-config
```

Clearly some of these clash with some Homebrew-installed packages.

```
$ ls /usr/local/bin/*-config
/usr/local/bin/Magick++-config   /usr/local/bin/libpng-config
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config     /usr/local/bin/libpng16-config
/usr/local/bin/MagickCore-config /usr/local/bin/pcre-config
/usr/local/bin/MagickWand-config /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
/usr/local/bin/Wand-config       /usr/local/bin/python-config
/usr/local/bin/freetype-config   /usr/local/bin/python2-config
/usr/local/bin/gdlib-config      /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config
```

Answer (score 4):

Such clashes are entirely possible.  When you install softwares that depends on Python using Homebrew, you want it to see Python packages and libraries installed via Homebrew but not those installed by Anaconda.

My solution to this is not putting

```
export PATH=$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

into `.bashrc`. Normally, you'll just use Python and `pip` installed via Homebrew and packages installed by that `pip`. Sometimes, when you are developing Python projects that is convenient to use Anaconda's [environment management mechanism](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) (`conda create -n my-env`), you can temporarily do `export PATH=$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH` to turn it on. From what I gathered, one important benefit of using Anaconda compared to using regular Python is that `conda create -n my-env anaconda` will not duplicate package installations unnecessarily as `virtualenv my-env` will when you have a large number of virtual environments. If you do not mind having some degree of duplication, you could just avoid installing Anaconda all together and just use `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 3):

It's entirely possible you won't notice any problems. On the other hand, you may have some pretty frustrating ones. It all depends on what you use and how your `$PATH` is ordered. Homebrew will take whatever file has precedence in your `$PATH`; if another Homebrew package needs to use Homebrew-installed config files and it sees the Anaconda versions first, it doesn't known any better than to use the wrong ones. In a sense, that's what you *told* it to do.

My recommendation is to keep things simple and clean. Unless you have a particular reason to keep Anaconda on your `$PATH`, you should probably pop it out and `alias` anything you need. Alternatively you could just install the things you require (e.g., numpy) via Homebrew and eliminate Anaconda altogether. (Actually, that's *really* what I would do. Anaconda comes with way more stuff than I have any reason to be dumping onto my machine.)

I don't know what your `$PATH` looks like, but in my experience, keeping it short and systematic has a lot of advantages.

Comment: This is only true if you're build a package that specifies a dependency on `:python`, which will add Anaconda's bin directory to the PATH in Homebrew's isolated environment. In that case, you can expect conflicts. You won't experience this with most packages.